# How can I get timestamp in minutes using PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

When I send a form on my web, the insert query saves the current date on my DB using the function now().

Now, I'm trying to get this column in minute format to calculate other thinks that I need, but I don't know how to do that.

For example, I have this:

"2013-05-08 08:30:00"

And I want this (now 8.50):

"20" <- In minutes

Thanks

Comment: In the first line of the example the minutes are "30". In the second, "50". In the third "20". Can you explain a little better what you want?

Comment: Because between 8.30 and 8.50 pass 20 minutes

Comment: Ok, but what do you want if now is 9:40? A result of 70 or 10?

Comment: Yes, 70. I need the difference in minutes between now and the date in DB.

Comment: Now it is clear, thanks. I submitted an answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

OK, let's suppose you have a table with a timestamp:

```
CREATE TABLE ex (t timestamp);
INSERT INTO ex VALUES ('2013-05-08 8:30'::timestamp);
```

And you want the difference in minutes between the column `t` and `now()`. You can get that using the `extract` function:

```
SELECT extract(epoch from (now() - ex.t)) / 60 FROM ex;
```

`epoch` is the number of seconds from the "epoch" for `date` and `timestamp` types, but is't just the number of seconds in the interval for `interval` types. By dividing it by 60 you get what you want (if you want an integer number of minutes just `trunc` it.)

Comment: OMG. This community is amazing. YOU are amazing. Thanks so much, it works perfect!!